# Is it possible to open another Web Browser form the current browser

Tags: javascript

**Is it possible to Open another web Browser from current web browser using JavaScript...??**

For Eg :If i am using Mozilla Firefox to view a web site and while clicking on a particular link (like an online payment mechanism), it must switch the browser to the Internet Explorer even if its not been given as a default browser.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? (give a reason people..) I'm actually very interested in seeing if it's possible

Comment: If you look a bit more into how a browser and operating system work you'll find out that this is not possible due to obvious security reasons.

Comment: @elclanrs Sir actually it is possible if i am writing a java Code so don't say that it is impossible.

Comment: What I meant is that it is NOT possible from the browser. Of course you can open applications from your own applications, but that's not the point.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not. There is nothing special about a browser; it's just an executable like any other program. If this was possible, it'd be possible to execute an arbitrary program from a website, thus you could trick the user into running a malicious program.

Answer (score 0):

no. it is not possible because of security restrictions.

Comment: illustrate .. how it is not possible because of security restriction?

Answer (score 0):

It possible to open another Web Browser form the current browser but conditions apply*.

The browser on which the application is running and the default browser should be different. :)
This [link](http://johnbokma.com/mexit/2008/08/19/java-open-url-default-browser.html) or this [link](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/345944/open-htm-files-in-default-browser-with-java#) will prove helpful.
Try it. It is possible.